# Notify raspberry pi of new entry in MySQL database on a VPS

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, raspberry-pi, publish-subscribe

I have a VPS with a static IP address running MySQL and Apache server on it and I have a raspberry pi in my home for doing smart IoT stuff. The raspberry pi is connected to the internet and does not have a valid IP address.

The question is how can my raspberry pi be notified of a new entry in MySQL database in the VPS?
I know that it is possible with polling the database continuously, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: This can be done with a database trigger and a user defined function call. You will have to script a call to a mechanism to do the update of the Rpi. There are a variety of ways of doing this e.g. ssh, ftp, mqtt etc. Checkout the link below for the Mysql piece: https://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html?m=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of feature is often called *publish/subscribe*. One client program can publish a message, and others, having subscribed ahead of time, get the message pushed to them.

Unfortunately, MySQL has no publish/subscribe: noway to send a message to a client program like a python program on your rpi.

You could investigate redis; it's often used for the kind of work you're doing. https://redis.io/topics/pubsub